# Uncaught Error: [$injector:modulerr] Failed to instantiate module yeomanTestApp due to: Error: [$injector:unpr] Unknown provider: e

Tags: angularjs, gruntjs, yeoman-generator

I'm using yeoman generator for scaffolding angular web application with requirejs. Its working fine but when I tried to concat and minifying all the js file into a single file through grunt task runner its started giving me above mentioned error. I've researched online about the issue and common solution is I may be mis-spelled any service injecting in the module or service does not exists, I've cross checked again all the spelling, quotation marks etc everything seems fine but still I'm unable to resolve this issue.

Here is my app.js file where my main module with dependencies is listed.

```
 return angular
.module('arteciateYeomanApp', [
'arteciateYeomanApp.controllers.MainCtrl',
'arteciateYeomanApp.controllers.AboutCtrl',
'arteciateYeomanApp.services.Xhr',
'arteciateYeomanApp.services.Common',
'arteciateYeomanApp.controllers.ArtworkCtrl',
'arteciateYeomanApp.controllers.AddAccountCtrl',
'arteciateYeomanApp.controllers.AddArtgroupCtrl',
'arteciateYeomanApp.controllers.AddArtistCtrl',
'arteciateYeomanApp.controllers.AddArtworkCtrl',
'arteciateYeomanApp.controllers.AddCampaignsCtrl',
'arteciateYeomanApp.controllers.AddGenreCtrl',
'arteciateYeomanApp.controllers.AddInstitutionCtrl',
'arteciateYeomanApp.controllers.AdminSignupCtrl',
'arteciateYeomanApp.controllers.ArtistInfoCtrl',
'arteciateYeomanApp.controllers.DirectUserSignupCtrl',
'arteciateYeomanApp.controllers.ErrorCtrl',
'arteciateYeomanApp.controllers.ForgotPasswordCtrl',
'arteciateYeomanApp.controllers.GroupBuyingCtrl',
'arteciateYeomanApp.controllers.LoginCtrl',
'arteciateYeomanApp.controllers.AdminLoginCtrl',
'arteciateYeomanApp.controllers.ResetPasswordCtrl',
'arteciateYeomanApp.controllers.SignupCtrl',
'arteciateYeomanApp.controllers.UnblockUserCtrl',
'arteciateYeomanApp.controllers.UpdatePasswordCtrl',
'arteciateYeomanApp.controllers.DashboardCtrl',
'ngRoute','ngResource']).config(.....);
```

here is grunt task which I'm running for minifying the js files.

registering task

```
grunt.registerTask('dev', ['requirejs' ]);
```

Here is task running script

```
requirejs : {
    compile : {
        options : {
            baseUrl : "<%= yeoman.app %>/scripts",
            mainConfigFile : "<%= yeoman.app %>/scripts/main.js",
            name : "main",
            out : "requireArterciate.js"
        }
    }
}
```

Please let me know if I'm doing something wrong here.

Comment: It's impossible to say what's e. Error message contains call stack which may be helpful to figure out which service caused the error but it was omitted from the question. The problem is most likely caused by the fact that the app isn't ready for minification because the services weren't properly annotated. Use https://docs.angularjs.org/guide/di#using-strict-dependency-injection

Answer (score 0):

If you need to minify the angularjs code, then use the following standard format syntax to define the controller and to inject the dependencies. Refer [Dependency Injection](https://docs.angularjs.org/guide/di)

```
angular.module('test').controller('testController', testController);
testController.$inject = ['$scope', '$rootScope'];
function testController($scope, $rootScope) {};
```